# Really close a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller

I have an application that push and remove a lot of viewControllers on an UINavigationViewController. 
All viewControllers have an UIWebView.
Suppose I have 2 viewControllers (A,B) and the rootViewController of the navigationViewController.

If I have to show A:

```
[navigationViewControlller pushViewController:A animated:YES]
```

After if I have to show B and hide A:

```
[navigationViewControlller popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES] //so I return to the root VC
[navigationViewControlller pushViewController:B animated:YES]
```

I can have more vc dependently on user action.

Now if I want finally close a vc (and free memory) I do:

```
[A willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[A removeFromParentViewController];
[A.view removeFromSuperview];
```

But I doesn't see the memory drop, and if I use Safari for debug the webViews I can see that the webView associated at the vc just closed still exists.

I think there is some references that keep alive the vc, but I'm not able to find it.
Any suggestion to find this reference or to close and destroy vc object (and all references to it)?

Comment: check if A exist in navigation stack and if it exist's then remove it from navigation stack

Comment: when I have to close a vc I'm on the root of the navigationController. Here if I check navigationController.viewControllers I have only the rootVc in the array

Comment: View Controllers are released when you "pop it off the stack". Trying to call any of those lines you posted to "finally close a vc" will do nothing, as `A` will not exist at that point. If it *does* exist, you have created a retain reference to it - so don't do that. You need to show whatever you are doing in your code that is giving you a reference to `A`.